# adding properties to an object

Tags: javascript, object

I wrote this code and it`s simple , i have an empty object which will contain some other objects as properties , but the object stays empty and don`t add the needed properties ..

```
let buildProfileClientValidator = function(form , rules){

    let elements = {};

    function init(){
       //Some code that works fine
       addElement(elementName , elementType);
       addElement(elementName , elementType);

        //the elements object should now have some other objects as properties  
        //but it`s empty !!!!
        console.log(elements);
     }

     function addElement(elementName , elementType){
        //this condition works fine 
        if( !elementExist(elementName) ){
        //console.log(elementName , elementType); also works fine -> the values of  elementName , elementType are present
        elements[elementName] = {
            type  : elementType,
            value : '',
            rules : (rules[elementName] == undefined) ? '' :  rules[elementName].split('|')
         };
       }
     }
 }
```

so what i`m missing ?!

Comment: Please show us your actual code, including the `elementExist` function.

Comment: @ScottMarcus https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0ec45b639313cdeb14f3

Comment: Before I go through your code, can you tell me why you are using let everywhere? Are you doing this just because or do you have a particular reason?

Comment: let was introduced in es6 and it`s block scoping mechanism (variable is only available between the scope it was decleared in {//block} )

Comment: I know what it is. I'm asking if you have a particular reason for using it.

Comment: Because it modifies the traditional way that scope works in JavaScript and can cause confusion with other code that doesn't use it. Just because we now have this capability doesn't mean it's meant to be used everywhere.

Comment: In addition, let declarations are hoisted (like var variables), but cause a temporal dead zone, which can cause issues when they aren't taken into consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After examining your code, but not knowing how `buildProfileClientValidator` gets called (and specifically what the `rules` parameter is), I can trace the problem to this line:

```
 (rules[elementName] === undefined) ? '' :  rules[elementName].split('|')
```

I have modified your code (to make it testable) in the following fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/hssbsL19/40/) and when I replace that line with a static value, the code works.

Comment: your answer was sort of right , when i changed the object property from rules to elementRules the object properties was added just fine :)) thnk you for your help ^_^

Comment: Glad to help, but looking at your GitHub code, I don't see any variable called `elementRules`. I only see the `rules` parameter being received on the first line. Anyway good luck!

Comment: What I meant is changing the proerity on the dynamically created objects , thanks again

Comment: Ah, yes. the property name was not being seen as a property name, but rather as the variable passed into the master function.